# Родственны ли слова "дразнить" и "дерзкий"?

Tags: этимология

У Фасмера это предположение никак не озвучивается, и вообще этимология слова `дразнить` [представляется довольно туманной](http://enc-dic.com/fasmer/Draznit-3964.html), а у меня возникло предположение по аналогии с `мерзкий` и `мразь`, что это могут быть ступени одного корня с `дерзкий`. С другой стороны, тогда слово `дразнить` должно было бы быть старославянским, что как-то трудно предположить; также нет никаких следов восточнославянской формы `*дорознить`. Понимаю, что это спекуляция, у которой мало шансов оказаться истинной, но не могу найти конкретного опровержения.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Дразнить` — ст. сл. раздражити < протосл. *razdraziti, *razdražati (< *razdrazjati) возможно связано с ие. корнем *der- «драть, деру» в его нулевой степени чередования *draz-.

`Дерзкий` — ст. сл. дрьзати < протосл. *dʲr̥zati < ие. *dhr̥su- «смелый, наглый, гордый, сильный», имеющее соответствие в разных ие. языках.

Поэтому кажется маловероятным этимологическое родство этих слов.

А восточнославянской формы *дорознить нет из-за того же, из-за чего нет и формы *дороть вместо «драть»: восточнославянское полногласие возникло из древних звукосочетаний типа *tort*, *tolt* при перестройке слогов под действием закона открытых слогов, в нашем же случае имеем древнее звукосочетание dra, которое закону открытых слогов не противоречило и в перестройке не нуждалось, поэтому оно и осталось неизменным.